# postgresql to_json() usage, convert to columns as key-values json

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I am trying to accomplish the following in postgresql

My table structure is

```
postgres=# select * from t_test;
 var1 | var2 | var3 
------+------+------
    1 | A    | v1
    1 | B    | v2
    2 | A    | u1
```

I want the output to be grouped by var1. var2 and var3 must become json key values. Something like this:

```
 var1 |  result
------+------------
    1 | { A: v1, B: v2 }
    2 | { A: u1 }
```

I could not understand the to_json function clearly from documentation. Can someone help ?

Comment: SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/eb3cd . **Please** provide data as CREATE TABLE and INSERTs in future.

Comment: Looks annoyingly hard with the json support in 9.3, which is ... less than entirely comprehensive. You really need 9.4's `json_object_agg` for this.

Answer (score 0):

They say `select to_json(table_name.*)` might work

Answer (score 0):

In 9.3 (as tagged) do string aggregation:

```
select v1, format('{%s}',string_agg(format('"%s":"%s"',v2,v3), ','))::json
from t
group by v1
;
 v1 |       format        
----+---------------------
  1 | {"A":"v1","B":"v2"}
  2 | {"A":"u1"}
```